# Swich over from tab to another in terminal tab

Tags: command-line, irc, irssi

I am using irssi and when i have only one irssi in a single tab i can switch around between different channels using alt + 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc.
but when i open up a new tab the alt + number keys doesent work anymore and wont change channels anymore, the different tabs that is open instead swiches around.

Comment: What terminal emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Check the shortcuts of your terminal emulator, make sure Alt+1 and friends are not bound to the action of switching tabs.

Alternatively, you can press `ESC` followed by the given number in irssi, instead of using the Alt modifier.